# Using Double to subtract currencies in Java

Tags: string, double

I want to subtract currencies in java and from what I have read I can use Double or BigDecimal. The problem is I cant get either to work exactly as I want.

What I want to do is the following.

```
Double amount1 = 25.50;
Double amount2 = 120.80;
```

I then want to subtract amount1 from amount2 which works, but I do not want the answer to be 95.3, I want it to be 95.30 and then convert this value to a String.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Format the difference.

```
Double amount1 = 25.50;
Double amount2 = 120.80;

Double diff = amount2 - amount1;
String diffString = diff.ToString("N");
```

Answer (score 0):

the value of 95.30 is equal to the value of 95.3. however, you can do for example

```
string str = (amount2 - amount1);
str += "0";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved it, I used the following.

```
double amount1 = 25.50;
double amount2 = 120.80;
double price = amount2-amount1;
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
String wihan = formatter.format(price);
```

Answer (score 0):

Number format -

```
 class TstNumberFormat{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.text.NumberFormat f =  null;

    try {
        Locale ll = new Locale("en", "US");
        f = java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(ll);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        f = java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance();
    }

    Double amount1 = 25.50;
    Double amount2 = 120.80;
    f.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    Double ans = amount2 - amount1;
    String ansStr = f.format(ans.doubleValue());
    System.out.println("format :" + ansStr);

}
```

}

see the java doc for Locale and Number format for more information http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/text/NumberFormat.html